# Creating a Multi Selection Checkbox List in Side-by-Side Cell Across Row in Excel

Tags: excel, checkbox, multipleselection

I'm using VB code created by L42 on 4/27/14 that creates a checkbox list in a single cell.

```
Option Explicit
Dim fillRng As Range
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim LBColors As MSForms.ListBox
Dim LBobj As OLEObject
Dim i As Long

Set LBobj=Me.OLEObjects("LB_Colors")
Set LBColors = Target

   If Not Intersect(Target, [B2]) Is Nothing Then
      Set fillRng = Target
     With LBobj
       .Left = fillRng.Left
       .Top = fillRng.Top
       .Width = fillRng.Width
       .Visible = True
     End With
   Else
     LBobj.Visible = False
     If Not fillRng Is Nothing Then
         fillRng.ClearContents
         With LBColors
            If .ListCount <> 0 Then
              For i = 0 To .ListCount -1
                 If fillRng.Value = Then
                     If .Selected(i) Then fillRng.Value = .List(i)
                 Else
                     If .Selected(i) Then fillRng.Value = _
                         fillRng.Value & "," & .List(i)
                 End If
              Next
         End With
         Set fillRng = Nothing
      End If
    End If

End Sub
```

The code works perfectly and I was able to extend the checkbox list to the cells in complete column by changing the (Target, [B1:B40]). Following this logic, I thought that I could extend checkboxes C and D columns by (Target, [B1:D40]. However, after selecting desired items in B column and clicking or tabing over to C column, the entire checkbox moves with selected items without writing in the previous cell.  I would like to be able to tab over or click to the next cell in the row and have same checkbox items that populates that cell with item selected, independent of the previous cell.  Then tab or click to succeeding cells and do the same and have cells retain and display selected the items. Can this code be modified to do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

to always put the values in the cell, just change your code to something like this:

```
Option Explicit
Dim fillRng As Range

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

  Dim LBColors As MSForms.ListBox
  Dim LBobj As OLEObject
  Dim i As Long

  Set LBobj = Me.OLEObjects("LB_Colors")
  Set LBColors = Target

  LBobj.Visible = False
  If Not fillRng Is Nothing Then
    fillRng.ClearContents
    With LBColors
      If .ListCount <> 0 Then
        For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
          If .Selected(i) Then
            If fillRng.Value = "" Then
              fillRng.Value = .List(i)
            Else
              fillRng.Value = fillRng.Value & "," & .List(i)
            End If
          End If
        Next
      End If
    End With
    Set fillRng = Nothing
  End If

  If Not Intersect(Target, [B1:D40]) Is Nothing Then
    Set fillRng = Target
    With LBobj
      .Left = fillRng.Left
      .Top = fillRng.Top
      .Width = fillRng.Width
      .Visible = True
    End With
  End If

End Sub
```

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5461205/dirk-reichel)_italic_**bold**'creating multiple selection checkbox in side-by-side-cells' Dirk Reichel, excellent!!! Thank you, very much.  The code that you provided works just as I described and requested.  However, when I tab over to the next cell, even though the selections from the previous cell are displayed, the checkbox selections do not clear and are carried over to the next cell.  Is there a way to clear the checkbox as it moves from one cell to the next?  Thanks again for sharing your expertise.  It is greatly appreciated!  Gerald Davis

Comment: In that case you need to initialize them again by the use of `unload` instead of `hide`. Or deselect inside the loop... still that behavior should also be in your old code.